# Access file in Blob storage from cluster

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

I want to know how to connect my cluster to a file on the blob storage , more detail I want to start a program wordcount on a txt file that is in the blob storage using my cluster to analyze the various differences of analysis in correspondence with the change of the nodes.For upload the on blob i used azure blob container.
Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Since you tagged this as **hadoop** - there are well-documented approaches to using blobs with Azure's hadoop service (HDInsight). There's no way to publish a tutorial here. You should visit azure.com, look at the documentation (which includes blob+wordcount samples for both Java and c#), and then ask specific questions when you run into issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to access your blob storage - using connection string or Sas. The documentation has more detail - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/ 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/